Send packets from physcial netwrok interface to vritual
I have a virtual machine with one NIC and one network interface accordingly.
I created TAP virtual interface to test my local app and setted IP to it:
dtap0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.49.243.168  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether d2:28:8d:59:9e:68  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.49.243.167  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.49.243.255
        ether 00:50:56:b3:f5:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 60405  bytes 4427551 (4.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 94  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13460  bytes 8583604 (8.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2597  bytes 4149581 (3.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2597  bytes 4149581 (3.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I want to ping dtap0 locally from my real interface ens192.
If I try to ping 10.49.243.168 but RX packets on dtap0 doesn't increase.
How to set up the interface correctly so that I can send ping to it locally?
